# Date format not working correctly - string to date conversion

Tags: ios, swift, date

How do I convert my below date string into Date format.
My code seems to not work

```
// sDate: Sun Feb 21 2021  
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "DAY MONTH DATE YEAR"
let dat = String(sDate)
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dat)!
print("Date:", date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd yyyy"
```